# Junit using groovy expected exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, junit

I have Spring boot application. I use Junit+Mockito to unit test it. All the test cases were written using Java. I recently made a decision to write test cases using Groovy though the application code will remain in Java.

I encountered a weird scenario while testing expected exceptions.

**Scenario 1: Testing Expected exception using Junit +  Groovy (without shouldFail):**

```
    @Test(expected = NoResultException.class) 
    void testFetchAllNoResultsReturned() throws Exception {
        List<Name> namesLocal = null;
        when(Service.fetchAllNames(id)).thenThrow(
                new NoResultException(""))
        namesLocal = (service.fetchAllNames(id)
        assert(namesLocal==null)
        verify(service, times(1)).fetchAllNames(id)
    }
```

As per the above test case, ***service.fetchAllNames*** call should throw a NoResultException. This aspect of testing seems to work well. However, the ***assert*** and ***verify*** after that are not called. As soon as the exception is encountered, the method execution stops. However, my earlier test case written in Java worked perfectly well. This issue happened only after I switched to Groovy.

After doing some Google search I found there is a method called ***shouldFail***  provided by ***GroovyTestCase*** class which can be used for this scenario as per this [link](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/11/groovy-goodness-testing-for-expected.html). And it did resolve my issue.

**Scenario 2: Testing Expected exception using Junit + Groovy (with shouldFail ):**

```
    @Test
    void testFetchAllNoResultsReturned() throws Exception {
        List<Name> namesLocal = null;
        when(Service.fetchAllNames(id)).thenThrow(
                new NoResultException(""))
        shouldFail(NoResultException.class) {
            namesLocal = (Service.fetchAllNames(id)
        }
        assert(namesLocal==null)
        verify(Service, times(1)).fetchAllNames(id)
    }
```

My doubt is, is this how it is supposed to work or am I missing something. If this is how it is supposed to work, is there any reason behind Groovy doing it this way? I tried to look for reasons on the internet but I couldn't get many leads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, the assert and verify after that are not called. As soon as the exception is encountered, the method execution stops. However, my earlier test case written in Java worked perfectly well.

Given this code in java:

```
@Test(expected = NoResultException.class) 
void testFetchAllNoResultsReturned() throws Exception {
    List<Name> namesLocal = null;
    when(Service.fetchAllNames(id)).thenThrow(
            new NoResultException(""))
    namesLocal = (service.fetchAllNames(id)
    ....
}
```

Irrespective of what you have after `service.fetchAllNames(id)`, the call will throw an Exception and the test case ends there. Since you have an expected exception defined, the test case will pass. So the assert and verify after this line of code are never executed in java.

I am not familiar with groovy but from the documentation  it looks like your second example using shouldFail is the correct way to test for exceptions in groovy. The `shouldFail` does not terminate the program - so its similar to putting your method call in a `try catch` in java

Comment: Note that in the OP's second snippet the `namesLocal` field isn't needed